# Microsoft Migration Database Tool Improper character error

Tags: json, azure, database-migration, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-import-data/#Prerequisites to upload a json file to Azure DocumentDB. As soon as the upload gets going, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: The resource name presented contains invalid character '/'.
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ValidateResource(Resource resource)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__33.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

I cant seem to find an documentation on this or maybe i dont know where to look. I would like some guidance on what this means and how to fix it. My guess is that "/" is an invalid character somewhere in my document, perhaps at line 33.

This is the document up to line 33 if that is what it indicates.

```
[
{
"name":"Cabinet De Lespinasse",
"accountid":2953,
"address":null,
"city":null,
"country":null,
"createdAt":null,
"heading":null,
"headingid":null,
"latitude":null,
"longitude":null,
"objectId":null,
"phonenumber1":null,
"website":null,
"display":null,
"email":null,
"aboutUs":"Education: Graduated from the Faculty of Law, State University of Haiti, 1983, Types of Practice: Established in 1877, the law office is specialized in intellectual property law for trademark and patent, insurance and commercial matters. Does not handle collection, Languages: Creole, French, English",
"Verified":false,
"Brands":null,
"Products":null,
"Services":null,
"Facebook":null,
"Instagram":null,
"googlePlus":null,
"Twitter":null,
"LinkedIn":null,
"Youtube":null,
"Pinterest":null,
"paymentMethods":null,
"languagesSpoken":null
 },

 {//<--This is line 33//
"name":"Cabinet Villejoint",
"accountid":2952,
"address":null,
```

Update:

When I upload one object in the following format, the upload succeeds. I removed the date field per @larry's comment below.

```js
{
   "name": "Western Union Agence Belmart ",
   "accountid": 2851,
   "address": "Route de Tabarre,",
   "city": "Port-au-Prince",
   "country": "Haiti",
   "heading": "Money Transfer Locations",
   "headingid": 428,
   "latitude": null,
   "longitude": null,
   "objectId": "0NM7Bav1Lp",
   "phonenumber1": "+509 3859 6346",
   "website": "http://868.ht",
   "display": "Western Union Agence Belmart",
   "email": null,
   "aboutUs": null,
   "Verified": false,
   "Brands": null,
   "Products": null,
   "Services": null,
   "Facebook": null,
   "Instagram": null,
   "googlePlus": null,
   "Twitter": null,
   "LinkedIn": null,
   "Youtube": null,
   "Pinterest": null,
   "paymentMethods": null,
   "languagesSpoken": null
  }
```

However, when I had a second object like below the upload fails. Any idea what is going on here?

```js
  [{
    "name":"Western Union Agence Belmart ",
    "accountid":2851,
    "address":"Route de Tabarre,",
    "city":"Port-au-Prince",
    "country":"Haiti",
    "heading":"Money Transfer Locations",
    "headingid":428,
    "latitude":null,
    "longitude":null,
    "objectId":"0NM7Bav1Lp",
    "phonenumber1":"+509 3859 6346",
    "website":"http://868.ht",
    "display":"Western Union Agence Belmart",
    "email":null,
    "aboutUs":null,
    "Verified":false,
    "Brands":null,
    "Products":null,
    "Services":null,
    "Facebook":null,
    "Instagram":null,
    "googlePlus":null,
    "Twitter":null,
    "LinkedIn":null,
    "Youtube":null,
    "Pinterest":null,
    "paymentMethods":null,
    "languagesSpoken":null
  },
  {
    "name":"Western Union Agence Belmart ",
    "accountid":2853,
    "address":"Route de Tabarre,",
    "city":"Port-au-Prince",
    "country":"Haiti",
    "heading":"Money Transfer Locations",
    "headingid":428,
    "latitude":null,
    "longitude":null,
    "objectId":"0NM7Bav1Lp",
    "phonenumber1":"+509 3859 6346",
    "website":"http://868.ht",
    "display":"Western Union Agence Belmart",
    "email":null,
    "aboutUs":null,
    "Verified":false,
    "Brands":null,
    "Products":null,
    "Services":null,
    "Facebook":null,
    "Instagram":null,
    "googlePlus":null,
    "Twitter":null,
    "LinkedIn":null,
    "Youtube":null,
    "Pinterest":null,
    "paymentMethods":null,
    "languagesSpoken":null
  }]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the comment `//<--This is line 33//` actually in the JSON? JSON does not support comments.

Comment: That is not in the json. there are no comments in the json. i was just pointing out what was on line 33 the best way i could. I guess your question directs me to see if there are specifics to the format the Azure DocumentDB accepts. I will look for any "/" to start...

Comment: You might try running your JSON through http://jsonlint.com. If it passes there but is not accepted by the data migration tool, then there is likely a bug in the data migration tool because I've found DocumentDB to accept all proper JSON but no JSON extensions. It's particularly frustrating for some that JavaScript Date() objects are not accepted.

Comment: Thank you Larry. I have date in the json object that looks like this:    "createdAt":"10/26/2015 7:27:55 PM". Is that the kind of date that gives problems? I also broke up the date to 200kb json files and tried uploading via the document explorer. I get upload failed but no error spec. How do i know what is wrong in that case. Also, i linted the data prior to uploading. Thank you

Comment: I don't think that's your problem. What you have is a string representation of a date. Strings are supported by JSON. As an aside, you might be better off converting dates to ISO-8601 format. That's how the .NET SDK saves them.

I would go into divide and conquer mode now. Take half of the JSON and see if only one or both halves fail. Half a failing one again and see if it still fails... You'll eventually get down to a single row and the problem will either be obvious, or you'll be able to post a minimal example so others can duplicate the issue and give you advice.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate the issue. I used the two document JSON file and the import tool and it worked perfectly on Windows 10. Maybe try uninstalling the tool and re-installing it? Also, have you checked that you have Microsoft .NET Framework 4.51 or later installed?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you're specifying an Id field in the Target Information, and if so, what you've chosen?

Comment: I have not specified an idea field. I have 'accountid' for my own purposes but figured i would rely on the documentdb generated id as stated in the docs.

Comment: I cannot re-create your error; I took your two-document array as posted and imported via the tool, no issue. Did you download a pre-built version of the tool, or did you download the source and build it yourself?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone i am on a mac and was using the microsoft migration tool through parallels on VisualStudio2015 with .Net v.4.51. As that was really taxing on my machine, i switched to trying to upload via the Azure portal document as noticed above. I have tried various versions of validated json up to now. the only thing that imports for me in the Document Explorer on the Azure Portal is one single json file. The errors thrown by the portal for the two object example above is invalid content.

Comment: OIC. That makes more sense now. The Azure Portal "Add Document" feature is only designed to upload a single JSON document. It expects that the outer most level is an Object with curly braces and not an array with square brackets. Since you are on a Mac (I am too :-)) your best bet might be to use the node.js SDK and write a short program to accomplish your upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct answer was provided by @larry maccherone below in that DocumentDb's Document Explorer in the Azure Portal only lets you upload one json object at a time. I missed this in the documentation or it doesnt say it there. That is, however, the result I experienced. Thanks, Larry.